# Simple terminal "game"

Tags: c#, terminal

So I've been trying to make a simple text-based terminal game to get myself more familiar with using c#, and I have no idea how to get the player back to the beginning so they can unlock the door, here's what I tried.  I apologise for the spaghetti code you're about to witness:

```
bool IsGameRunning = true;
bool hasKey = false;
if(isGameRunning == true){ Start();}
if(isGameRunning == true && Start() == "go forward" && hasKey == false){

while(true){
Middle();
if(Middle() == "go back"){
Start();
break;
}
}
} 

 else if(isGameRunning == true && Start() == "go left"){
while(true){
hasKey = true;
Key();
 if(Key() == "go back"){
Start();
break;
 }
 }} else if(isGameRunning == true && Start() == "go forward" && hasKey == true){
Console.WriteLine("You tried the key...THE DOOR IS STILL LOCKED!!!");
 }
//methods
static string Start(){
    
while(true){
Console.WriteLine("You are in a dark room, what do you do?");
   string? input = Console.ReadLine();
if(input == "look around")
{
Console.WriteLine("It is too dark to look around.");}



 else if(input == "go left"){

return "go left";
}
else if(input == "go forward"){
return "go forward";
} else{
Console.WriteLine($"I don't know what '{input}' means.");}
}
}
static string Middle(){
while(true){
Console.WriteLine("You decided to pick a direction and go forward.You stumbled upon a door, the door is locked.");
string? input = Console.ReadLine();
if(input == "go back"){
Console.WriteLine("You decided to return back from where you came.");
return "go back";
} else {
    Console.WriteLine($"I don't know what '{input}' means.");
}
}
}
static string Key(){
while(true){
Console.WriteLine("You decided to pick a direction and go left.You found a key!");
string? input = Console.ReadLine();
if(input == "go back"){
Console.WriteLine("You decided to return back from where you came.");
return "go back";} else{
Console.WriteLine($"I don't know what '{input}' means.");
}

}
}
```

I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) before posting a question. Your formatting makes that code impossible to read and it's hard to provide any help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to figure out the exact problem that you want to fix with how the code is formatted, but hopefully, this info will allow you to rewrite it into a cleaner state that is fixable.

Even inside of an `if` statement, calling the `Middle()` function will run all of that function's code. So basically this (code below) is running `Middle()` twice and only checking for the return value for the one in the `if` statement.

```
Middle();
if(Middle() == "go back"){
```

If you want to use the return value in an if statement like that, try calling the function once and assigning the return value to a variable that you can check. Like this:

```
string middleInput = Middle();
if (middleInput == "go back") {
```

Or a slightly more confusing, but valid way like this:

```
if (Middle() == "go back") {
```

Also would really recommend using an IDE (integrated development environment) like Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code, or Jetbrains' Rider. This will make writing clean code a lot easier.